# Why does the method only return 0 ? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

The idea of this program is to calculate the person's weight and age on each planet. and Life class is supposed to be the one who do the calculations and return the values correctly.

my problem is when i run the program it returns 0 ! but I want it to do the calculations and return different values.

Person Class

```
package solarsystemplanets;
public class Person {
private String name;
public int age;
public double weight;

//Constructors
public Person(String n, int a, double w) {
    n = name;
    a = age;
    w = weight;
}

public Person(){
    name = "";
    age = 0;
    weight = 0;
}

//Setters (Mutator)
public void setName(String n) {
    n = name;
}

//Getters (Accessor)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
    }
    

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

//PrintDetails Method
public String toString() {
    return "Person" + " name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", weight=" 
            + weight;
}
}
```

Life Class

```
package solarsystemplanets;
public class Life extends Person {

private int earthDays;
public double []surfaceGravity;
public int []planetsDays;

//Constructors
public Life (int e, double []s, int []p){
    earthDays = e;
    surfaceGravity = s;
    planetsDays = p;
}

public Life (int ee){
    earthDays = 365;
    surfaceGravity = new double[]{0.38,0.91,1.0,0.38,2.34,0.93,0.92,1.12};
    planetsDays = new int[]{88,225,365,2,12,29,84,165};
}

public Life(){
    this.surfaceGravity = new double[]{0.38,0.91,1.0,0.38,2.34,0.93,0.92,1.12};
    this.planetsDays = new int[]{88,225,365,2,12,29,84,165};
}


//Setters (Mutator)
public void setEarthDays(int e) {
    earthDays = e;
}  

//Getters (Accessor)
public int getEarthDays() {
    return earthDays;
}

public double[] getSurfaceGravity() {
    double array1[] = new double[surfaceGravity.length];
    for(int i =0; i < surfaceGravity.length; i++){
        array1[i] = weight * surfaceGravity[i];
    }
    return array1;
}

public int[] getPlanetsDays() {
    int array2[] = new int[planetsDays.length];
    for(int i =0; i < planetsDays.length; i++){
        array2[i] = (age * getEarthDays())/ planetsDays[i];
    }
    return array2;
}




//PrintDetails Method
public String toString(int i) {
    return  "surfaceGravity=" + getSurfaceGravity() + ", planetsDays=" + getPlanetsDays();
}



}
```

Main

```
package solarsystemplanets;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SolarSystemPlanets {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Person person = new Person();
    Life life = new Life();
    Planet planet = new Planet();
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    File file = new File ("Solar System Planets");

    //User Info
    System.out.println("What is Your Name ? ");
    person.setName(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Age: ");
    person.age = input.nextInt();
    while (person.age <=0){
        System.out.println("error. Please Enter Your Age Again: ");
        person.age = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Weight: ");
    person.weight = input.nextInt();
    while (person.weight <=0){
        System.out.println("error. Please Enter Your Weight Again: ");
        person.weight = input.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i =0; i<planet.planetName.length; i++){
        System.out.println(planet.planetName[i]);
        System.out.println("Your Weight = " + life.getSurfaceGravity()[i] + " 
        Your Age = " + life.getPlanetsDays()[i]);
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that now is a really good time to learn how to use a debugger. Step through your code slowly. At every point, look at the next line of code and predict what it will do. Step over the line, and see what the *actual* result was. When there's a difference between the two, that may well be a bug - so look more carefully, and fix it if it's a bug. (Learning about unit testing would be helpful too, but using a debugger probably comes first.)

Comment: (I'd also suggest getting your IDE to format your code, so that the methods are indented within the class declaration.)

Comment: Why does Life extend Person? Usually you extend a class to indicate an "is-a" relationship, but Life is not a Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting user inputs on `person` object and using `life` object to calculate and print data. As these objects are different fields in `life` object remains zero.

Life extends Person, so it has inherited person fields. Set all user inputs on `life` object.
Also, you've forgot to set `earthDays` on `life` object.

Comment: THANK YOU so so much! I did what u said and its solved :)  thanks a lot again.